# Multistore configurable item still showing after status = "disabled" and visibility = "Not visible individually"

Tags: configurable-product, multistore, visibility

To start: "Display Out of Stock Products" is also set to "No". So that's not the problem.
So i have a configurable item with two simple items. One of them is specifically for the storeview France "disabled" and the visibility = "Not visible individually". See the simple item below

[image]

And here the configurable item

[image]

But
Even after indexing en flushing on storeview France the swatches still give both simple items, BUT SIZE XXL should not appear!! See below
[image]
PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: Is there a quantity field for each product in the configurable product edit page under configurations?

Comment: Yes, but quantity is not the problem. The problem is that if a item is in the "associated" list, it will be displayed. Even if it is disabled for that specific storeview. And there is no "associated field" for the specific storeview, only for the total overview. So if anybody knows how to hide a swatch for a specific storeview, please help